# Phrase for don't fool yourself

Tags: phrase-request

I am actually looking for a phrase which means"don't fool yourself "

For example : The phrase "get over yourself" is used for someone who thinks that they are more important than other people.

In the same way please let me know if there is any phrase that is used to say someone to stop fooling themselves?

Comment: I think "don't fool yourself" is fine.

Answer (score 9):

One could say '**don't kid yourself**' - meaning don't delude or fool yourself into believing something.

Comment: How about don't lull yourself

Comment: @engfan: No - to "lull" means to calm someone down, or cause them to relax. It doesn't have anything to do with misleading.

Comment: @psmears : https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lull

Comment: @engfan: 'lull' meaning 'fool' can really only occur in the construction "lull somebody into a false sense of security" (as in your link). So you can say "don't lull yourself into a false sense of security." But you can't say "don't lull yourself."

Comment: Or, as @kevin says, *don't fool yourself* is idiomatic.

Comment: @engfan: As TonyK says, the phrase "to lull (somebody) into a false sense of security" is a fixed phrase, and means to "make someone relax more than they should". The sense of misleading/deception comes from "false", not from "lull" (which gives the sense of letting one's guard down).

Answer (score 4):

Three expressions I can think of at the moment.

Example #1:

> **Don't be a fool!** She's lying. She doesn't really love you. All she wants is your money.

Example #2:

> **Get your head out of the clouds!** No one will give you a job without education. If you're not gonna study hard, you're not gonna succeed in life!

Example #3:

> **Don't fall for it**! She doesn't really love you. It's your money she's after!

Answer (score 2):

How about:  "Open your eyes!" "Wake up!" But if you are trying to be clear about something just say what you have to say, don't try and make it sound cool.

You want to ask or suggest to another person to not  to be 'taken in' by something?

Where I grew up, saying "Wake up!" means, stop dreaming and pay attention. Or look at what you are seeing -- wake up your mind to what is really happening.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear!!

Comment: Okay, I've never heard or seen the expression *yourself self*.

Comment: Sorry!!  my bad I didn't see that. Thanks for the correction 

Comment: that's okay, so I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "take your head out of the sand"

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seems to be the exact phrase..

Comment: @engfan  You are right, and it's not exactly the same, but it is similar and appropriate, depending on context.